# Get the last document and filter nested array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-compass

First time playing with MongoDB (and pymongo) and I have the documents below.
I'm trying to make the following query:

1. get the top 1 entry, ordered by `time_added` descending
2. from that subset of documents (let's call it `entries.stocks`), get the stocks that price is less than a `balance` value
3. order by volume and price in that order.

From what I've googled it seems this can be done with [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) but I only managed to do the first step with:
`db.entries.find().sort('date_added', -1).limit(1)`

Documents:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5fcd2582a7a12288df9a6bf3"
    },
    "stocks": [
      {
        "name": "stock_name",
        "volume": 73,
        "price": 135
      },
      {
        "name": "stock_name",
        "volume": 44,
        "price": 324
      }
    ],
    "date_added": {
      "$date": "2020-12-06T18:40:02.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5fcd2582a7a12288df9a6ad0"
    },
    "stocks": [
      {
        "name": "stock_name",
        "volume": 342,
        "price": 43
      },
      {
        "name": "stock_name",
        "volume": 544,
        "price": 66
      }
    ],
    "date_added": {
      "$date": "2020-12-05T18:40:02.000Z"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You can use the aggregation array operator [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to get the subset of the documents (of an array field, `stocks`) matching a condition.